# Why does ghostscript replace fontnames to "CairoFont"?

Tags: pdf, ghostscript, cairo

I use ghostscript to optimize pdf files (mostly with respect to size), for which it does a great job. The command that I use is:

```
gs -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress \
   -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -sOutputFile=out.pdf in.pdf
```

However, it seems that this replaces fonts (or subsets them) and does not preserve their names. It replaces it by CairoFont. How could I get ghostscript to preserve the fontnames?

**Example:**
A simple pdf file (created with Inkscape), with a single text element in it (Nimbus Roman) as an input (`in.pdf`):

[image]

for which `pdffonts` reports:

```
name                                 type              emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- --- --- --- ---------
PMLNBT+NimbusRomanNo9L               Type 1            yes yes yes      5  0
```

However, after running ghostscript over the file `pdffonts` reports:

```
name                                 type              emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- --- --- --- ---------
OEPSCM+CairoFont-0-0                 Type 1C           yes yes no       8  0
```

So, is there a way to have ghostscript (or libcairo?) preserve the name of the font?

The input file is uploaded [here](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=34322247769476492869).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ghostscript doesn't change the font name, but there are, in fact, several different font 'names' in a PDF file.

In the case of your file the PDF FontDescriptor object has a name

```
<<
  /Type /FontDescriptor
  /FontName /PMLNBT+NimbusRomanNo9L
  /Flags 4
  /FontBBox [ -168 -281 1031 924 ]
  /ItalicAngle 0
  /Ascent 924
  /Descent -281
  /CapHeight 924
  /StemV 80
  /StemH 80
  /FontFile 7 0 R
>>
```

which refers to a FontFile stream

```
  /FontFile 7 0 R
```

That stream contains the following:

```
%!PS-AdobeFont-1.0: NimbusRomNo9L-Regu 1.06
%%Title: NimbusRomNo9L-Regu
%Version: 1.06
%%CreationDate: Thu Aug  2 13:14:49 2007
%%Creator: frob
%Copyright: Copyright (URW)++,Copyright 1999 by (URW)++ Design &
%Copyright:  Development; Cyrillic glyphs added by Valek Filippov (C)
%Copyright:  2001-2005
% Generated by FontForge 20070723 (http://fontforge.sf.net/)
%%EndComments

FontDirectory/NimbusRomNo9L-Regu known{/NimbusRomNo9L-Regu findfont dup/UniqueID known pop false {dup
/UniqueID get 5020931 eq exch/FontType get 1 eq and}{pop false}ifelse
{save true}{false}ifelse}{false}ifelse
11 dict begin
/FontType 1 def
/FontMatrix [0.001 0 0 0.001 0 0 ]readonly def
/FontName /CairoFont-0-0 def
```

Do you see the FontName in the **actual** font ? Its called `CairoFont-0-0`

This brings me back to a point which I reiterate frequently here and elsewhere; when you process a PDF file with Ghostscript and emit a new PDF file using the pdfwrite device you are not 'optimising', 'converting', 'subsetting' or in a general sense manipulating the content of the original PDF file.

What Ghostscript does is interpret the PDF file, ths produces a set opf marking operations (such as 'stroke', 'fill', 'image' etc) which it sends to the selected Ghostscript device. Most Ghostscript devices will then use the graphics library to render the operations to a bitmap and when the page is complete will write the bitmap to a file. The 'high level' or 'vector' devices instead repackage the operations into another Page Description Language. In the case of pdfwrite, that's a PDF file.

What this means in practice is that the emitted PDF file has nothing (apart from appearance) in common with the original PDF file. In particular the description of the objects may be different.

So in your case, the pdfwrite device doesn't know what the font was called in the original PDF object. It *does* know that the font that was defined was called Cairo-0-0 so that's what it calls the font when it emits it.

Frankly this is another piss-poor example from Cairo, to go along with defining each page as containing transparency whether it does or not, the FontName in the Font object is **supposed** to be the same as the name in the Font stream.

Its pretty clear that the FontName has been altered, given the rest of the boilerplate there.

Comment: Awesome explanation. Thanks for that! I had a feeling that libcairo was involved in the problem, but just wasn't able to figure out, that inkscape actually uses it when producing the pdf in the first place. Would you see a simple way of fixing the font name in the FontFile stream?
What tools did you use to read the steams from the pdf file?

Comment: I used MuPDF (another Artifex product) to decompress the original PDF file and had Ghostscript write out its own PDF file using -dCompressPages=false and -dCompressFonts=false. After that it was just an editor to read the content. Your only hope of 'fixing' ths would be to put the /FontName in the font stream back to Nimbus.... but that is not a simple task. First you would need to decompress the file, then edit the font stream, then (because PDF is a binary format with a xref) use MuPDF to fix the edited file (mutool clean). There's nothing GS can do with the PDF file as it stands.

Comment: Ok, I see. Thank you for your explanations. They have been most helpful!